# Convert JSON based on a key value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, transformation

I get some records from a database in the following JSON format:

```js
data: [{
    "y": "0.652008685",
    "x": "-0.13926217",
    "geneName": "ADAMTS2",
    "cond": "Cell"
  },
  {
    "y": "-3.486001",
    "x": "-2.295312",
    "geneName": "IGSF22",
    "cond": "ECM"
  },
  {
    "y": "-3.597706",
    "x": "-2.672138",
    "geneName": "OXA1L",
    "cond": "ECM"
  }
]
```

I would like to transform the above result and group the `y`,`x` and `geneName` name/value pairs based on the `cond` key using `JavaScript`.

The result I'd like is shown below:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Cell',
    color: '#fff',
    data: [{
      "name": "ADAMTS2",
      "x": -0.13926217,
      "y": 0.652008685
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'ECM',
    color: '#000',
    data: [{
        "name": "IGSF22",
        "x": -2.295312,
        "y": -3.486001
      },
      {
        "name": "OXA1L",
        "x": -2.672138,
        "y": -3.597706
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For every different grouping I'd like to add an extra name/value pair `color`.
Is there any smart and quick way to do it using `JavaScript` by avoiding the naive approach of the for loops?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did color come from?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I would like to change the value of the `color` for every different grouping of `cond`. I don't care about the actual value of the colour. I'm mostly interested in the logic behind that.

Comment: Change how?  You haven't detailed that part of the problem in your question, as far as i can tell.  If that's not essential to your question, including it is just causing confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Array.prototype.reduce to group common objects by object.cond, like so:

```js
var data = [{
    "y": "0.652008685",
    "x": "-0.13926217",
    "geneName": "ADAMTS2",
    "cond": "Cell"
  },
  {
    "y": "-3.486001",
    "x": "-2.295312",
    "geneName": "IGSF22",
    "cond": "ECM"
  },
  {
    "y": "-3.597706",
    "x": "-2.672138",
    "geneName": "OXA1L",
    "cond": "ECM"
  }
];

var dataMap = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  // create root-level object for a name if it doesn't already exist
  if (!result[item.cond]) {
    result[item.cond] = {
      name: item.cond,
      color: ''/*not sure what your logic is here*/,
      data: []
    }
  }
  
  // add current item to the root-level object data
  result[item.cond].data.push({
      name: item.geneName,
      x: parseFloat(item.x),
      y: parseFloat(item.y)
  });
  
  return result;
}, {/*resulting map*/});

// last step is to get an array of the values since that's the desired format
data = Object.values(dataMap);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I think this approach is quite clear and understandable but it does not produce exactly the required output as it doesn't group the "data" under the same parent "name". What I want to print the "name" key as many times as the distinct "name" keys are. Please see my question above to understand better what I'm explaining here. Thanks

Comment: @gkoul missed that. See updated snippet, which also fixes your requirement for converting string to float

Comment: It's almost done, the only thing is that the outer `name`, `color` and `data` keys should not have double quotes. I know it sounds very weird but this is the required input of the [HighCharts scatterplot](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/scatter/) I'm trying to create.

Comment: I finally managed to do it in the following way. data=data.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:'); Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce` here. Make a object whose key is basically `cond` and then from that object transform a array using `.map`.

```js
var x = {
  data: [{
      "y": "0.652008685",
      "x": "-0.13926217",
      "geneName": "ADAMTS2",
      "cond": "Cell"
    },
    {
      "y": "-3.486001",
      "x": "-2.295312",
      "geneName": "IGSF22",
      "cond": "ECM"
    },
    {
      "y": "-3.597706",
      "x": "-2.672138",
      "geneName": "OXA1L",
      "cond": "ECM"
    }
  ]
};

x.data = Object.entries(x.data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  let cond = el.cond;
  delete el.cond;
  
  if(acc.hasOwnProperty(cond)){
    acc[cond].data.push(el);
  }
  else{
    acc[cond] = {};
    acc[cond].data = [el];
  }
  
  return acc;
  
}, {})).map(el => {
  return {name: el[0], data: el[1].data};
});

console.log(x);
```

Comment: The above approach seems to work well. Can you help me to remove the double quotes from `x` and `y` values as shown in the requested result of my question? I know I can remove them using the `parseFloat()` function in general but I don't know how to change your code above. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{
"y": "0.652008685",
"x": "-0.13926217",
"geneName": "ADAMTS2",
"cond": "Cell"
  },
  {
    "y": "-3.486001",
    "x": "-2.295312",
    "geneName": "IGSF22",
    "cond": "ECM"
  },
  {
    "y": "-3.597706",
    "x": "-2.672138",
    "geneName": "OXA1L",
    "cond": "ECM"
  }
]

series = []
definedName = []

data.forEach(function(item) {
  var ind = definedName.findIndex((element) => {
    return element == item.cond;
  });
  if (ind === -1) {
    obj = {
      name: item.cond,
      color: '#fff',
      data: [{
        "name": item.geneName,
        "x": item.x,
        "y": item.y
      }]
    }
    definedName.push(item.cond)
    series.push(obj)
  } else {
    obj = {
      "name": item.geneName,
      "x": item.x,
      "y": item.y
    }
    series[ind]["data"].push(obj)
  }
});

console.log(series)
```